# Sidekiq::DelayedMailer not sending email using .delay method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis, sidekiq

I am having an issue sending delayed messages using Redis/Sidekiq using the .delay method. I currently use ActionMailer and it works like a charm. I can run..

```
Notifier.new_user_welcome_email(name).deliver
```

with zero issues. But as soon as I try to run..

```
Notifier.delay.new_user_welcome_email(name)
```

it chokes in my Sidekiq retries with the error..

```
ArguementError
Wrong number of arguements (3 of 0)
```

This is under the Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer class.

The biggest kicker is that this works perfectly on my test server but is choking on my live server. I have reset both Redis and Sidekiq on the live server and it has not remedied it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the full backtrace.

```
…ctionpack-3.2.17/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb:  45:in `initialize'
…ctionpack-3.2.17/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb:  45:in `new'
…ctionpack-3.2.17/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb:  45:in `lookup_context'
…9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.17/lib/action_mailer/base.rb: 457:in `process'
…9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.17/lib/action_mailer/base.rb: 453:in `initialize'
…9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.17/lib/action_mailer/base.rb: 439:in `new'
…9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.17/lib/action_mailer/base.rb: 439:in `method_missing'
…sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/extensions/action_mailer.rb:  17:in `perform'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:  48:in `block (3 levels) in process'
….1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb: 109:in `call'
….1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb: 109:in `block in invoke'
….1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb: 111:in `block in invoke'
…-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:   6:in `call'
….1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb: 111:in `block in invoke'
…kiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:  49:in `call'
….1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb: 111:in `block in invoke'
…idekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:  11:in `block in call'
…/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:  22:in `with_context'
…idekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:   7:in `call'
….1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb: 111:in `block in invoke'
….1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb: 114:in `call'
….1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb: 114:in `invoke'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:  47:in `block (2 levels) in process'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb: 102:in `stats'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.12.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:  46:in `block in process'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:  25:in `call'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:  25:in `public_send'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:  25:in `dispatch'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:  67:in `dispatch'
…by/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/future.rb:  15:in `block in new'
…1/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:  59:in `call'
…1/gems/celluloid-0.14.1/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:  59:in `block in create'
```

Comment: These jobs will go to the "default" queue.  Have you configured your production workers to process the "default" queue?

Comment: Give the full backtrace.

Comment: Mike Perham - The backtrace is up

Comment: infused - do the other jobs (.deliver) not use the "default" queue? I see that the default queue is active but I don't show a .yml file in my config file for sidekiq to configure this. As is, it works natively.

Comment: @zacmccool Did you found the reason of this issue? I'm having the same issue on one of my prod servers.

Comment: We moved these delayed methods into a their own workers and called the worker as needed. It's mainly needed for any mass email sent.